# What is the best database for storing nested data similar to "files and folders" in large volumes and numbers?

Tags: .net, database, mongodb, graph, neo4j

The main requirement is to store nested data. Finally, the last node ends up in the file and these files are stored in the object storage.
Of course, in addition, to inserting, reading, displaying, updating, and controlling the accesses of nesting data are among the requirements.
Currently, I am thinking between MongoDB and Neo4j and even a combination of the two, Of course, Mongo is my first priority; Because the comprehensiveness, libraries, and frameworks of Mongo in .NET are better than neo4j, but is MongoDB really a good choice for storing relations?

The last option is to keep nodes in MongoDB and relations in Neo4j, which is a difficult option.

Answer (score 1):

The particular database you use is slightly less important than the design pattern necessary. What you are referring may be suitably solved with a [nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), and can work within many datastores, [including MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-nested-sets/).

They essentially rely on a "left" and "right" value, where the leaves/branches of another branch are contained between the left and right value of the parent. The example given on the MongoDB website:

**Creating Model:**

```
db.categories.insertMany( [
   { _id: "Books", parent: 0, left: 1, right: 12 },
   { _id: "Programming", parent: "Books", left: 2, right: 11 },
   { _id: "Languages", parent: "Programming", left: 3, right: 4 },
   { _id: "Databases", parent: "Programming", left: 5, right: 10 },
   { _id: "MongoDB", parent: "Databases", left: 6, right: 7 },
   { _id: "dbm", parent: "Databases", left: 8, right: 9 }
] )
```

**Accessing Data**

```
var databaseCategory = db.categories.findOne( { _id: "Databases" } );
db.categories.find( { left: { $gt: databaseCategory.left }, right: { $lt: databaseCategory.right } } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The design pattern used is very important but ultimately, the data must be stored in the database and it should not become a bottleneck.
Is nested data update functionality the same in Mongo and Neo4j?
In Mongo, many functions have to be managed at the application layer, but is it the same in Neo4j?